# Automatic windows app installation without admin rights

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, deployment

We have a business application which requires to use windows API libraries such as user32.dll etc. to take screenshots of the user desktop. This is currently built using C#.NET / VB.NET.

The business requirement now is to find a way to be able to execute/deploy the application to user machines with least user intervention. Additionally, the user might not have admin rights on his machine.

Please share any suggestions on the options. It would have been great to move the windows application into a web application, but I can only think of options such as ActiveX or Silverlight which might be able to user low level APIs, but these are already being discontinued.

ideal would have been some approach, where the user visits a website, maybe cliska button to install, and that website installs this windows application on the user machine.

The target environment is Windows 8. So I believe we may can assume that the .net framework would be existing already, BUT we do not know if in future perhaps the application in future might require any external referenced dll which might need to be pushed to the user machine.

Comment: It would be great to have more details on the targeted environment. Butler1233 answer is probably the cleanest as long as your users have at least the same .NET framework version installed. If it's not the case, they will have to install prerequisites and that will (almost certainly) require admin rights.

Comment: On last thing:

ClickOnce > ActiveX (only supported by IE, you don't want that) / Silverlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the standard clickonce application deployment that comes with Visual Studio, you can deploy the website to a website, and users can install form the webpage, installing any prerequisites for the program.

In addition, it installs to a user's appdata, so no admin rights are required. The only time admin rights are needed is when you install/update the .Net framework.

For bonus points, the clickonce deployment will automatically update the application on the client's PC when you publish new updates.